# Having two item index in same line

Tags: latex

I have written the following in latex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item Ans:
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

and I get an output like

```
Ans:
   1. text
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get an output like this

```
Ans: 1. text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Ans:]
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]